# Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to build a node.js backend,I have a usecase that i should connect everytime to the server and not to the database ,see one of the webservices:

```
router.get('/CriticalityGraph/:server/:user/:password/:database/', function(req, res, next) {

    user = req.params.user;
    password = req.params.password;
    server = req.params.server;
    database = req.params.database;
    criticalityState=req.params.criticalityState

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: user,
        password: password,
        server: server,
        database:database

    };




    sql.connect(config, function (err) {




        var request = new sql.Request();


        request.query("SELECT MachineName, alarmState, criticality FROM MachineTable  ORDER BY criticality DESC"
            , function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {

                    for(i=0;i<recordset.recordsets.length;i++) {
                        res.send(recordset.recordsets[i])

                    }
                    sql.close();
                }

            });
    });

});
```

Now i want to access to this webservice simultaneously from 2 browsers and i'm throwing `node.js Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first`.

Any suggestions to fix the problem?

Comment: You aren't calling `sql.close()` if you encounter an error - that might not be your current problem but it could be at some point. Also, sending the username and password via URLs seems a bit...dangerous, anyone with access to your server's logs could have the keys to the castle.

Comment: Just saw another issue, you are (potentially) calling `res.send` `recordsets.length` times, calling `res.send` more than once will result in an error, which could lead to a state where an exception is thrown and `sql.close()` is never called.

Comment: I'm calling `sql.close()` after the request

Answer (score 0):

Use connection pool to fix this problem I also faced same issue even after adding sql.close()

Use below connection pool code to fix this issue.

```
         new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
            return pool.request().query("")
             }).then(result => {
               let rows = result.recordset
               res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
               res.status(200).json(rows);
               sql.close();
            }).catch(err => {
                  res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}"})
                 sql.close();
            });
```